# Return inner-class from a inherited virtual template class in C++

Tags: c++, inner-classes, class-template

`Derived<T>` inherits from `Base<T>`. `Derived<T>::m` should return an `Derived<T>::Inner` object. Whats the mistake, I don't get it.

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
    class Inner {
    public:
        virtual void x() = 0;
    };
    virtual Inner m(std::string arg) = 0;
};

template <typename U>
class Derived : Base<U> {
public:

    class Inner : Base<U>::Inner {
    public:
        virtual void x();
    };
    virtual Inner m(std::string arg);
};

template <typename U>
Derived<U>::Inner Derived<U>::m(std::string arg) {
    std::cout << "calling Derived::m() " << arg << std::endl;
    return new Inner();
}

template <typename U>
void Derived<U>::Inner::x() {
    std::cout << "calling x" << std::endl;
}

Derived<std::string>* d = new Derived<std::string>();
Derived<std::string>::Inner* inner = d->m("test");
inner->x();
```

I get the following error:

```
invalid covariant return type for 
   'Derived<U>::Inner Derived<U>::m(std::string) [with U = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]'
overriding 'Base<T>::Inner Base<T>::m(std::string) [with T = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to override a function based on return type. The class `Base::Inner` is not the same as `Derived::Inner`, and so you can't override the `m` method in the base class from the derived class.

The `m` method in the `Derived` class needs to return `Base::Inner`. However, that will lead to [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) so you can't do that directly. Instead you either have to return a reference or a pointer.

I suggest the latter, by using [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Maybe something like:

```
template<typename U>
class Base
{
public:
    class Inner { ... };

    using inner_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Base<U>::Inner>;

    virtual inner_ptr m(const std::string&) = 0;
};

template<typename U>
class Derived : public Base<U>
{
public:
    Base<U>::inner_ptr m(const std::string&);

    class LocalInner : public Base<U>::Inner { ... };
};

template<typename U>
inline Base<U>::inner_ptr m(const std::string& arg)
{
    return Base<U>::inner_ptr(new LocalInner);
}
```

Comment: Why not `std::unique_ptr`? That should be the default unless there is an explicit need for sharing.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Yes, Yes, a thousands Yes! :D

Comment: @MatthieuM. LOL, did it trigger a pet peeve?

Comment: @TemplateRex: I am tired of repeating this over and over, too many people think that `shared_ptr` is the hands-off approach, like it was a GC or something, and are oblivious to the issues of cycles.

Comment: Thanks! But calling `Derived<std::string>* d = new Derived<std::string>();` results in an error: `error: dependent-name 'Base<U>::inner_ptr' is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type`. Changed the method slightly: `template<typename U>
inline typename Base<U>::inner_ptr Derived<U>::m(const std::string& arg)
{
    return Base<U>::inner_ptr(new Derived<U>::LocalInner());
}`